# Align the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, css, web

I would like to know if there is a way in css to align a div from the bottom.

I have a div next to a check box, and the top-left corner of the div is next to the top-right corner of the checkbox. But I want the bottom-left corner of the div to be next to the top-right corner of the checkbox.

```css
.ToolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block">
  <input id="checkbox1" value="true" type="checkbox">
</span>
<span class="ToolTip">
  <div class="BlockLevelDiv">
    There is a table in the div
  </div>
</span>
```

If my problem is not clear ask me some questions, I'm not fluent in English.

Thank You.

Comment: Please add a code what you have tried so far

Comment: The problem is that the html is generated from a Java Framework. I'm writting an example.

Comment: How is code generated is irrelevant. We need to see the output sent to browser - it's just html/css.

Comment: Regardless of how the markup is generated and/or processed it is expected that a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example be provided to accurately
 reproduce and demonstrate the issue described. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I was just trying to say that it generate some html code that's not really clean and understable but I agree with you and tried to write an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **x2** methods you can explore here:

**1)** `vertical-align: super` with `position: relative`

1. Change your `position` property value on the element `.ToolTip` to
   `relative` to benefit from the `vertical-align` property;
2. With the element now *back in the normal document flow*, and since
   the element in question is *already an inline-block*, declare
   `vertical-align: super`

**Example:**

```
.ToolTip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* additional */
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.ToolTip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* additional */
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<span class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block">
  <input id="checkbox1" value="true" type="checkbox">
</span>
<span class="ToolTip">
  <div class="BlockLevelDiv">
    There is a table in the div
  </div>
</span>
```

**2)** retain `position: absolute` and offset with `bottom` property

1. Retaining the `position` property with the value of `absolute` on `.ToolTip`, the element position can be offset with the `bottom` property;
2. As a requirement to the aforementioned solution, the containing element (of an absolutely positioned element) must be positioned `relative` as to maintain positioning *relative* to *the parent* - otherwise, the absolutely positioned element will be positioned *relative to the window*.

**Example:**

```
.ToolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* additional */
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.ToolTip {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* additional */
  bottom: 5px;
}

.relative-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative-container">
  <span class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block">
    <input id="checkbox1" value="true" type="checkbox">
  </span>
  <span class="ToolTip">
    <div class="BlockLevelDiv">
      There is a table in the div
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this complete response ! I learned a lot, I couldn't use the first solution because my div must stay in position: absolute otherwise it would have move a lot of things on my page but the second solution is just perfect I would never had think about this. Thanks again have a great day

Comment: @G.Sabathier No problem, happy I could help you.